# Send data from an HTML select to a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a scheduleMeet.jsp page

```html
<select name="Dept">
    <option value="Personalization">Personalization</option>
    <option value="WebDevelopment">WebDevelopment</option>
    <option value="MobileApp">MobileApp</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
```

And I want to send the data when the user selects one of the option from dropdown to a servlet.

Can someone suggest code snippet for the Servlet?

Comment: That's only `request.getParameter("Dept");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get multiple selection using :

```
String[] assignedResources = request.getParameterValues("Dept");
```

Comment: But how would the servlet know that from which jsp page it has to find the Dept Tag?

Comment: basically in your form you would have action = xyzServlet. So from JSP you will invoke xyzServlet and servlet would have all form details.

Comment: The servlet doesn't need to know from which JSP the tag is sent. It gets the actual value selected in the dropdown and doesn't "care" about its source. If YOU need to know from which JSP the value was sent, add another field to your JSP indicating from which page or business element the value was sent, allowing your JSP handle differently values sent under the same names/tags - but from different pages.

Comment: can u give a small code snippit  how to get data and then send data back to same jsp page

Answer (score 1):

```
String Department= request.getParameter("Dept");
```

So you will get data from one of option's value. If you don't believe it, you can print out the Department object like:

```
System.out.println(Department);
```